# Remove warnings coming in my web page while using applet

Tags: java, image, security, applet, resize

I have newly created one website.it contains applet.But while loading it shows a security warning.

[Resize multiple images online without losing quality](http://imageresizenow.in/resize-multiple-images-online-without-losing-quality/)

Plaese tell me how to remove this warning.

I have tried browsing in google, as I need to access the file system, I think I have to sign the jar file.  How to sign the jar file so that there should not be any warning like in the page?

[Resize with Custom dragging and create template and resize n number of images with high performance](http://imageresizenow.in/resize-multiple-images-online-without-losing-quality/)

Explain me all the steps while dealing with applet.

Comment: Same thing happens in http://imageresizenow.in/split-image-equal-pieces/

Comment: *"explain me all the steps while dealing with applet"*  Unfortunately that is 'too broad' for SO.  Unless you can accept my current answer in relation to a specific part of the question, that is the close vote I will be choosing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get a Java applet launched without warnings.  This is for the protection of the end user and cannot be changed no matter what we might do.

An applet that accesses the local file system certainly could *never* be launched without warnings.